# Measuring the ground coverage in % of a transparent getiff along a path of a vectorline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-cover

I am searching for a way to measure the ground coverage in QGIS. I have an high resoluted orhtomosaic of an agricultural plot trial where i have extracted the organic material on the surface:

[image]

The result of the extraction is a transparent orthomosaic with the organic material on the surface:

[image]

Now, i am looking for a way to measure the percentage of organic material of a determined area. The area is demarced by a buffered vectorline.

In my case thera are 14 vectors.

[image]

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the tool **Zonal Statistics**, you'll be able to produce different statistics of pixels by polygon and calculate your percentage based on that.

[image]